# "Action not allowed" - Even for empty functions

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google App Script I created from a Google Form. I have it published as an API executable and it's worked fine for the past few weeks.

Suddenly, I can't call any functions from Google App Script. It just returns "Action not allowed." Strangely, I can still call the functions normally through my web app via the execution API.

In the Dashboard API manager, I even tried unrestricting the API key, adding https//www.script.google.com and some other weird stuff.

This is in production and I really need it fixed.

Thank you.

Comment: It works as an Execution API, but not in the IDE?

Comment: Correct, although I might be onto something. I'll be back in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

**Cause guess:** The cause of the problem (my guess) is that I shared the folder containing the Form (which the script is created from) and the spreadsheet the form responses go to with "Anyone at  with link can edit", and somewhere permissions got screwy.

**Fix:** What I ended up doing was creating a *temporary project* from the Google API dashboard, got that project number, reassociated the *script* with that temporary project (through Resources > Developers Console Project). Then saved. Then went back and associated the script with the *original project* again, and I got a security permissions popup to allow access. It didn't appear otherwise.

Hope this helps someone.